# Getting _resp instead of resp response from API call with async/await in for...in loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vuejs2, async-await, vuex

I have a Vuex action wherein I need to loop through a list of objects, have a service send them to a REST endpoint via Axios, and then get the `data` and `response` back. I need to do it in such a way that I can get a count of successful POSTs so I can display a message. The problem that I'm having is using async/await and a `for...of` loop.

Here's what I have so far:

```
  async bulkSave({
    dispatch,
    getters,
  }, item) {
    let saveCount = 0;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
    for (const user of item.users) {
      const resp = await tenantUserService.save({
        user,
        tenantCode: item.tenantCode,
        skipUserCheck: true,
      });
      const { status, data } = resp;
      if (resp.status === 201) {
        saveCount += 1;
        dispatch('setSaveResponse', { status, data });
      }
    }

    dispatch('alertMessage/setApiResponse', {
      resp,
      component: getters.getComponent,
    }, { root: true });
    return resp;
  },
```

and this is the existing function that I'm working from that saves one record at a time:

```
async save({ dispatch, getters }, { service, item }) {
        const resp = await service.save(item);
        const { status, data } = resp;
        dispatch('setSaveResponse', { status, data });
        dispatch('alertMessage/setApiResponse', {
          resp,
          component: getters.getComponent,
        }, { root: true });
        return resp;
      },
```

with this as the `save` service being called:

```
  static async save(item) {
    const { user, tenantCode, skipUserCheck } = item;

    return await super.perform(axios.post(ServiceUrlProvider.gmiUrl().concat('/tenant/').concat(tenantCode).concat('/person'), user));
  }
```

I had initially tried using `.forEach()`, but since async/await doesn't work inside `forEach()`, I started trying for...of`based on answers like [this one][1]. However, esLint is telling me I can't have`await`inside a loop, and when I run this, my call to`tenantUserService.save()`just returns`_resp`:

[image]

What am I missing to make this work so that I can 1) get the item saved and 2) get the proper response so that I can increment `saveCount` and continue?

Comment: in `bulkSave`, you have `resp` as a const inside the for loop ... so where is the `resp` that you return outside that loop declared?

Comment: also, just as a point of view here ... your final `save` service doesn't need async/await really, since you `return` the only `await`ed value ... having said that, does `super.perform` return a Promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work with a couple minor tweaks:

```
  async bulkSave({
    dispatch,
    getters,
  }, item) {
    let saveCount = 0;
    const usersToUpload = item.users.length;
    let uploadPercentage = 0;
    let resp = {};
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
    for (const user of item.users) {
      resp = await tenantUserService.save({
        user,
        tenantCode: item.tenantCode,
        skipUserCheck: true,
      });
      const { status, data } = resp;
      if (resp.status === 201) {
        saveCount += 1;
        // Calculate the percentage of users that have been uploaded
        // Used for progress bar display.
        uploadPercentage = Math.round((saveCount / usersToUpload) * 100);
        dispatch('setUploadProgress', uploadPercentage);
        dispatch('setSaveResponse', { status, data });
      }
    }

    dispatch('alertMessage/setApiResponse', {
      resp,
      component: getters.getComponent,
    }, { root: true });
    return resp;
  },
```